# .htaccess Display shorter url in address bar that points to a real server folder path

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to shorten my urls in the address bar and for Google indexation purposes. For example, a real server directory path 
http://www.somewebsite.com/path1/path2/path3/ 
would display 
http://www.somewebsite.com/path3/

I've found many similar topics but no answer that seems to work for this particular case.

I have for example:

```
RewriteRule ^path3(.*)$ path1/path2/path3$1 (tried with with [L], [QSA,l], [R=301,...]...)
```

But this simply does a redirect and does not keep the short address in the browser.

My .htaccess file looks as follow:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served as `text/html` or `text/plain`.
AddCharset UTF-8 .html

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

#Trying to have a shorter url in address bar
RewriteRule ^path3(.*)$ path1/path2/path3$1
```

Comment: Sure, here you go.

Comment: It was meant to be an internal redirect. I changed the force www. rule (see above), cleared the cache and still have the same result.

Comment: Yes, it is a real physical path.

Comment: Try this rule `RewriteRule ^path3/.*$ path1/path2/$0 [L,NC]` and test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Gets a 404 not found

Comment: Move this rule up below last 301 rule. Also tell what URL are you using to test this rule

Comment: Thanks! It was a question of order. By moving the condition up in the file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to answer so that solution can be easily found for the problem stated.

There are couple of issues with the rules shown in question:

1. Since target paths are pointing to an existing directory and you don't have trailing `/` in target it is causing an external redirect by `mod_dir` module of Apache that appends a `/` at the end of directory path and performs a `301` redirect.
2. Incorrect positioning of rule.
3. Not critical but missing `L` and `NE` (no escape) flag from redirect rules which may cause problems for some cases.

With those suggestion final working `.htaccess` can be like this:

```
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served as `text/html` or `text/plain`.
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove .php and index; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]

# rewrite path3/ to /path1/path2/path3/ 
RewriteRule ^path3/.*$ path1/path2/$0 [L,NC]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided works for myself on my own test website, using the below .htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test2.txt/?$ /test.txt
```

This lets me have an optional trailing slash, and show the content of test.txt on /test2.txt.

Assuming your rewrite engine is on, can you replicate this behaviour? What version of Apache are you using? Is the path handled by a CMS at all?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Apache 2.4.7 Unbuntu. The path is not create by CMS, it points to an actual server file. You address bar keeps the /test2.txt?

Comment: I'm using Apache v2.4.6, and I've taken your entire .htaccess and replicated the `path1` and `path2`, with an end file of `path3` and `path3test` (to test the `$1` addition), and both URL masks work as provided in your current .htaccess.

Is path3 a file, or another directory?

Comment: Thanks. Was helpful to help me do testing.